# findByCriteria in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

In my generic Hibernate DAO which consists of a method `findByCriteria`

```
protected List<T> findByCriteria(Criterion... criterion) {
        Criteria crit = getSession().createCriteria(getPersistentClass());
        for (Criterion c : criterion) {
            crit.add(c);
        }
        return crit.list();
    }
```

Now myDao extends generic dao.Now how can i use findByCriterion to get objects satisfying certain conditions.Can any one give some examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know what `dao.Now` is but, you can use this method like this:

```
List<YourObject> result = findByCriteria(Restrictions.like("name", "Fritz%"));
```

Assuming that `YourObject` has a property `name` that should begin with *Fritz*

See [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html)